# Why does `renameTo` return false after deployment?

Tags: java

The call to `renameTo` is returning false. On my local machine,it works but when I deploy on the JBoss server it fails. I have checked all paths.

```
public boolean MoveCSVFile(String sFileName) {
    String dtFile = "";
    java.util.Date dt = new java.util.Date();
    SimpleDateFormat sdfd = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddhhmmss");

    try {
        File afile = new File(this.sInputPath + File.separator + sFileName);
        dtFile = System.getProperty("user.dir") + File.separator+"FilesUploaded" + File.separator+this.sSectionName;
        File destination = new File(dtFile);
        if(!destination.exists()) {
            destination.mkdirs();
        }

        dtFile = dtFile + File.separator + sdfd.format(dt) + afile.getName();
        File bfile = new File(dtFile);
        if(afile.renameTo(bfile)) {
            System.out.println("CSV moved...");
        } 
        else {
            System.out.println("CSV not moved...");
        }
    } 
    catch(Exception e) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: 1) Check permissions of directories. 2) throw the exception or log it so that you can get to know incase of exceptions

Comment: [Don't use the class `File`](http://java7fs.wikia.com/wiki/Why_File_sucks). It is outdated and uninformative. Switch to using `Path`, `Paths` and `Files`, and you'll get an appropriate `Exception`. And you should display or log the exception rather than do the same mistake as `renameTo` (return boolean - bad).

Comment: You should generally not `catch(Exception e)` (Pokemon, gotta catch 'em all?), but just the exceptions that are declared to be thrown sometimes. And NEVER ignore the exceptions, the information they provide is valuable and it can tell you what's wrong.

Comment: 1.i have given all permissions  2.It is returning false,no exception as such 3.whcih package is Path,Files is,i am using java1.6

Answer (score 0):

`Files.move` is more appropriate, though it may fail too.
The most simplest solution being, user rights; and a web server application may have a SecurityManager in place too. The thrown exception will clarify the cause.

In the date format `hh` was used, which is for a 12 hour format, `HH` for 24 hours.

```
public void moveCSVFile(String sFileName) throws IOException {
    java.util.Date dt = new java.util.Date();
    SimpleDateFormat sdfd = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss");

    Path afile = Paths.get(this.sInputPath, sFileName);
    Path bFile = Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.dir"),
            "FilesUploaded", this.sSectionName,
            sdfd.format(dt) + aFile.getFileName());
    Files.createDirectories(bFile.getParent());
    Files.move(aFile, bFile); //, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
}
```

Also let the caller catch any IOException and deal with it.

Comment: 1.i am using java 1.6, so cant use Files class i guess  2.Theres no exception,its just returning false

Comment: Do not forget HH. Try to write your own file copy. Sometimes a renameTo might not work between different disks. See [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#renameTo%28java.io.File%29). Probably Apache libraries have something too.

Comment: i copied my file in destination path and tried deleting source file,but didnt get deleted.

Comment: i am using multithreading,but i dont see any reason for that as not using any streams.